# (pool-2-thread-5) Got error closing channel JBREM00206

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jboss, kepler

My eclipse (Kepler) got stuck while starting the deployment by clicking RUN ON SER server (JBOSS 7.0.1 final).

I can successfully deploy the application through manual process (making war and copy the war to deployment directory and start the standalone.sh).

In short,I cannot able to run my application through eclipse but I can do it manually.

Please help.

The error:

```
19:27:30,111 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2)
Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999 19:27:30,127 INFO 
[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-5)
Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080 19:27:30,158 INFO 
org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-4) Starting JCA
Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.3.Final) 19:27:30,205 INFO 
[org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread
1-2) Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS] 19:27:30,377
INFO  [org.jboss.as.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) Started
FileSystemDeploymentService for directory
E:\jboss-as-7.0.1.Final\standalone\deployments 19:27:30,393 INFO 
[org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBoss AS 7.0.1.Final "Zap"
started in 1647ms - Started 93 of 148 services (55 services are
passive or on-demand) 19:27:30,393 INFO  [org.jboss.as.deployment]
(DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) Found TF_Webservices.war in deployment
directory. To trigger deployment create a file called
TF_Webservices.war.dodeploy 19:27:46,447 WARN  [org.jboss.as.protocol]
(pool-2-thread-5) Got error closing channel JBREM00206: Channel is not
open
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by defining maven war plugin in my pom .

```
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
          <directory>resource2</directory>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
```